# Replace values in dataframe from replacement table (from a file) pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

What I'm doing is reading the replacement table with pandas, and then transforming it to a dictionary with two lists. For the replacement I'm going through the dictionary and doing a df.replacement().

This solution works but I don't know if it's the most efficient, any ideas to improve it?

```
file = 'replacement_table.csv'
replace_table = pd.read_csv(file)

replace_dict = replace_table.to_dict('list')

for i in range(len(replace_table)):
    df = df.replace(replace_dict['Base name'][i],replace_dict['Destination name'][i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Reason'] = df['Reason'].replace(dict(zip(replace_table['Base name'], 
                                    replace_table['Destination name'])))
```

---

```
              StartTime  Duration                 Reason     AsarcoCategory  \
0  2022-10-01 12:12:09      16371  TRANSFER OF EQUIPMENT             Delay    
1  2022-10-01 20:00:00      27399          AHS DETENTION             Delay    
2  2022-10-05 20:00:00      26938     LACK OF EQ SUPPORT  Operational loss    
3   2022-10-08 5:00:16       9951          AHS DETENTION             Delay    

   Truck  
0  MH234  
1  MH237  
2  MH237  
3    MH2
```